# Angular Hide jQuery DatePicker When Clicked Outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker in an angular project.

```
<div>
  <!-- Anchor that toggles date picker -->
  <a class="datepicker button dropdown" ng-click="ctrl.showHideDatePicker">
    <span>Choose a date</span>
  </a>

  <!-- Date picker -->
  <div ui-date="options" ng-show="ctrl.showDatePicker"></div>
</div>
```

**Problem:** The datepicker will stay open until I select a date, or click the anchor tag again.

**Desired result:** I'd like the datepicker to close by clicking **anything** outside of the datepicker itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a click event to the body and check if the target element is the datepicker. If it isn't then hide the datepicker.

Not ideal as it uses some jQuery but unfortunately the jQuery UI datepicker doesn't come with an onBlur event.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.date"]);

app.controller("controller", function() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.showDatePicker = false;

  vm.options = {
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: '1900:-0'
  };

  vm.hideDatePickerOnBlur = function($event) {
    var $target = angular.element($event.target);

    // Target is the "Choose a date" link
    var isLink = $target.closest("#showDatePicker").length;
    // Target is in the datepicker
    var isDatePicker = $target.closest(".ui-datepicker").length;
    // Target is an element in the header of the datepicker (added this because isDatePicker was false when clicking either arrow even though they are descendants of the datepicker)
    var isHeader = $target.closest(".ui-datepicker-header").length;

    if (!isLink && !isDatePicker && !isHeader) {
      vm.showDatePicker = false;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-date/master/dist/date.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller as ctrl" ng-click="ctrl.hideDatePickerOnBlur($event)">

  <div>
    <!-- Anchor that toggles date picker -->
    <a id="showDatePicker" class="datepicker button dropdown" ng-click="ctrl.showDatePicker = true">
      <span>Choose a date</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Date picker -->
    <div ui-date="options" ng-show="ctrl.showDatePicker"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```